# What cdk directory in the Angular Material 2 source code?

Tags: angular-material2, angular-cdk

I am trying to understand how things work in Angular material 2, but I can't understand it :(
unfortunately, they did not write anything about those things, and I don't what those directories mean and I even don't know how to start the application. I am just trying to understand it because it's a good way to learn more.

I saw the `cdk` directory there, but I don't know what does it do! and the name does not make any sense for me

Comment: `cdk` is for [component dev kit](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta8-plasma-abacus-2017-07-06). If you want to mess around with it, fork the project, `npm install` and `npm run demo-app`

Comment: @WillHowell Thank you so much